# Using dart2js output with Cloud Code by Parse.com

Tags: node.js, dart, dart2js

First, I transpose the javascript example into a dart one.

JS

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {
  response.success('Hello world');
});
```

DART

```
import 'dart:js' show allowInterop;
import 'package:js/js.dart' show JS;

@JS('Parse.Cloud.define')
external void define(String name, Function func);

void main() {
  define('hello', allowInterop((req, res) {
    res.success('Yeah!');
  }));
}
```

Then I compile it using dart2js (with csp or not).

Finally I run `parse deploy` and I get

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at <error: TypeError: Object #<error> has no method '__lookupGetter__'>
    at main.js:2539:9
    at init.currentScript (main.js:2519:7)
    at main.js:2534:5
    at main.js:2542:3
```

and now, here I am...

How I could get it work on parse.com which is a nodejs env I presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is effectively not defined in the environement provided by parse.com, so I defined `self` such as `var self = this;` in the dart2js output.

I get a new error, about `success$1` is not defined. Well, that's true, my code is still incomplet...

Dart code should like this:

```
import 'dart:js' show allowInterop;
import 'package:js/js.dart' show JS, anonymous;

@JS('Parse.Cloud.define')
external void define(String name, Function func);

@JS()
@anonymous
class HttpResponse {
  external void success(String msg);
  external void error(String msg);
}

void main() {
  define('hello', allowInterop((req, HttpResponse res) {
    res.success('Yeah!');
  }));
}
```

Now, everything work. I can enjoy my sunday.